# How to calculate the derivative of composition map on smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-topology, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Given a smooth manifold $N$ of 4 dimension. By smooth manifold here, we mean that $N$ is a manifold with a smooth atlas $\,\mathcal A=\Big\{\big(U_i,\varphi_i:\, U_i\to\mathbb R^4\big) \big|\,i\in I \Big\} $.

Let
\begin{align}
x:\ N&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4
\\ p&\longmapsto x(p)=\big(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\big)(p)
\\ T:\ \mathbb R^4&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4
\\ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)&\longmapsto T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)
\end{align}
be diffeomorphisms. Then the map
\begin{align}
(T\circ x)^{-1}:\ \mathbb R^4&\longrightarrow N
\\ (u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)&\longmapsto x^{-1}\circ T^{-1}(u)
\end{align}
is a diffeormorphism and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1} }{\partial u_1}(u),\,\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1} }{\partial u_2}(u),\,\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1} }{\partial u_3}(u),\,\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1} }{\partial u_4}(u)
\end{align}
is a basis for $T_pN$ where $\,p=x^{-1}\circ T^{-1}(u)$.

My question is how to calculate the partial derrivative $\,\displaystyle\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1} }{\partial u_i}(u)\,$ in this problem ? I hope anyone could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: You're confusing $f$ and $x$, apparently. Just write the chain rule down in matrix notation. $D(T\circ x)(p) = DT(x(p))Dx(p)$. Now invert the matrix product to write $D(T\circ x)^{-1}(q)$, with $q=x(p)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh sorry, I will edit my symbol

Comment: @TedShifrin now since $\,x:\ N\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4$, how can we compute $Dx(p)$ ?

Comment: You can’t “compute” it in the setting of an abstract manifold. If $N$ is a submanifold with a specific parametrization, then you can compute $Dx^{-1}$ concretely.

Comment: @TedShifrin here is my solution

Comment: \begin{align}
D(T\circ x)(p)&=DT\big(x(p)\big)\circ Dx(p)
\\ &=J_T\big(x(p)\big)\cdot J_x(p)
\\ &=J_T\big(x(p)\big)\cdot\big[J_{x^{-1}}(u)\big]^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: But you wanted the derivative of the inverse? Also, $u$ should be $q$ there, right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: from there I think we can get 
\begin{align}
D(T\circ x)^{-1}(u)&=J_{x^{-1}}(u) \cdot\big[ J_T\big(x(p)\big)\big]^{-1}
\\ &=J_{x^{-1}}(u) \cdot\big[ J_{T^{-1}}(x)\big]
\end{align}
Hence we get 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\big(T\circ x\big)^{-1}}{\partial u_i}(u)=\frac{\partial T^{-1} }{\partial x_i}\big(x(p)\big)\cdot\nabla x^{-1}(u)
\end{align}

Comment: Of course you know what $J_T$ is. The last line is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin how was it wrong ?

Comment: Do you really want that $x$ is a diffeomorphism on $N$?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, I need the smoothness of $x^{-1}$, so

Comment: First, what does $\nabla x^{-1}$ mean? We want the $i$th column of the matrix product $J_{x^{-1}}(T^{-1}(u))\cdot T^{-1}$.

Comment: Then it does not work for arbitrary $N$, only for $N$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$. Is that what you want? What about $N = S^4$ for example?

Comment: @PaulFrost yeah, I think I want to consider $N$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space, which is alway isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and hence is also diffeomorphic.